# --disable-warnings + "ra" options do not stack well in pytest.ini

Tags: pytest

Trying to move some pytest options from direct cli call to the pytest.ini: I'm able to move the "--disable-warnings" flag to the .ini file, that looks like this:

**pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]
addopts = --disable-warnings
```

but when I want to add a `"-ra"`, like this, the "diable" is disregarded:

```
 [pytest]
  addopts = --disable-warnings -ra
```

OR

```
 [pytest]
  addopts =  -ra --disable-warnings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get a kind of the conflict here:

`--disable-warnings` option suppresses "the warning summary entirely from the test run output"
and on the other hand `-r` option tells pytest to show summary upon tests are passed

turns out `-r` to be having a priority